# Why have my buttons in my PyQt5 GUI stopped working?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am making a GUI in PyQt5 using the designer application, I added in a splash screen/loading screen for effect when opening, and now it seems that my buttons to log in and sign up no longer take the user to the dashboard when hitting the login button or the sign-up screen when hitting the sign-up button.

I added print statements into my code that I have now removed but it seemed to show that the code was indeed running as expected, it simply didn't produce an output. I have also started receiving this error when running my code using visual studio codes built in debugger.

```
QCssParser::parseColorValue: Specified color without alpha value but alpha given: 'rgb 255, 255, 255, 0'
```

I scoured the internet for error messages similar to this and only managed to find one or two forums that I didn't understand, having looked through the code for my .ui files, named splash.ui, dashboard2.ui, loginscreen.ui, and signupscreen.ui. I couldn't seem to find any instances of the code seeming to have an alpha value without it being specified.

Here is the GUI code:

```
import sys
import os
import time
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_EnableHighDpiScaling'):   
    PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps'):
    PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True)

###################################################################

class SplashScreen(QSplashScreen):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QSplashScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("splash.ui", self)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        pixmap = QPixmap("image.png")
        self.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def progress(self):
        for i in range(100):
            time.sleep(0.0111)
            self.progressBar.setValue(i)

class Login(QDialog): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(Login,self).__init__()
        loadUi("loginscreen.ui",self)
        print("0.5")
        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.loginfunction)
        print("0.75")
        self.password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.signup_button.clicked.connect(self.gotocreate)

    def loginfunction(self):
        dash = DashScreen()
        print("1")
        widget.addWidget(dash)
        print("2")
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
        print("3")
        # email = self.username.text()
        # password = self.password.text()
        # print("Sucessfully logged in with: ", email, "and password: ", password)

    def gotocreate(self):
        createacc = CreateAcc()
        widget.addWidget(createacc)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)

class DashScreen(QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(DashScreen,self).__init__()
        loadUi("dashboard2.ui",self)
        os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"

class CreateAcc(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CreateAcc,self).__init__()
        loadUi("signupscreen.ui",self)
        self.signup_button.clicked.connect(self.createaccfunction)
        self.password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.confirmpassword.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
    
    def createaccfunction(self):
        email = self.username.text()
        if self.password.text()==self.confirmpassword.text():
            password= self.password.text()
            print("Sucessfully created an account with: ", email, "and password: ", password)
            login=Login()
            widget.addWidget(login)
            widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)

# main
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
splash = SplashScreen()
splash.show()
splash.progress()
window = Login()
window.show()
splash.finish(window)
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
app.exec()
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The main problem is that you have a `widget` that you are not showing. The reality, though, is that you probably followed a YouTube tutorial that is known to provide lots of terrible suggestions (such as constantly creating and adding widgets to QStackedWidget instead of reusing them, or using QDialog for that purpose). I strongly recommend you to completely disregard it and look for other resources.

Comment: what widget am I not showing I can't seem to find it. Thanks for the suggestion anyways!

Comment: The widget named `widget`.